# All intent's extras are null while starting a new activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

This is an application with a list of dogs and information about the dog.
I'm trying to run a DetailActivity that contains information about a dog. It is launched after clicking the Show Details button, which has a setOnClickListener and runs the Intent, passing the name, age, hobby and other parameters of the dog to the running DetailActivity. But when I try to take those parameters in the DetailActivity code, they all equal null.

It's actually very simple and I've done the same thing in google course codelab before (now I decided to practice a bit) and I repeat everything as it's written there, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'll insert the DetailActivity and DogCardAdapter code below. You can also see all the code at this link on GitHub: https://github.com/theMagusDev/DogglersApp

DetailActivity.kt:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.dogglers.databinding.ActivityDetailBinding

class DetailActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailBinding
    private val TAG = "DetailActivity"

    companion object {
        const val DOG_IMAGE = "dogImage"
        const val DOG_NAME = "dogName"
        const val DOG_AGE = "dogAge"
        const val DOG_HOBBIES = "dogHobbies"
        const val DOG_SEX = "dogSex"
    }

    val dogImageResourceId = intent?.extras?.getString(DOG_IMAGE)
    val dogName = intent?.extras?.getString(DOG_NAME)
    val dogAge = intent?.extras?.getString(DOG_AGE)
    val dogHobbies = intent?.extras?.getString(DOG_HOBBIES)
    val dogSex = intent?.extras?.getString(DOG_SEX)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Setup view binding
        binding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val heOrShe: String = when(dogSex){
            "male" -> "He"
            else -> "She"
        }
        binding.dogName.text = dogName
        Log.d(TAG, "${dogAge.toString()}, ${dogName.toString()}, $dogHobbies, $heOrShe, $dogImageResourceId")
        binding.dogDescription.text = getString(R.string.dog_description, dogName, dogAge, dogSex, dogHobbies)
        //binding.dogImage.setImageResource(dogImageResourceId!!.toInt())
        binding.dogImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bella)
        Log.d(TAG, "dogDescription and dogImage were set")

        title = getString(R.string.details_about, dogName)
    }
```

Logcat:

```
2022-10-02 08:32:25.545 9660-9660/com.example.dogglers D/DetailActivity: null, null, null, She, null

2022-10-02 08:32:25.558 9660-9660/com.example.dogglers D/DetailActivity: dogDescription and dogImage were set
```

DogCardAdapter.kt:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.dogglers.DetailActivity
import com.example.dogglers.DetailActivity.Companion.DOG_AGE
import com.example.dogglers.DetailActivity.Companion.DOG_HOBBIES
import com.example.dogglers.DetailActivity.Companion.DOG_IMAGE
import com.example.dogglers.DetailActivity.Companion.DOG_NAME
import com.example.dogglers.DetailActivity.Companion.DOG_SEX
import com.example.dogglers.R
import com.example.dogglers.const.Layout.GRID
import com.example.dogglers.data.DataSource

/**
 * Adapter to inflate the appropriate list item layout and populate the view with information
 * from the appropriate data source
 */
class DogCardAdapter(
    private val context: Context?,
    private val layout: Int
): RecyclerView.Adapter<DogCardAdapter.DogCardViewHolder>() {

    // Initialize the data using the List found in data/DataSource
    val data = DataSource.dogs

    /**
     * Initialize view elements
     */
    class DogCardViewHolder(view: View?): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view!!) {
        // Declare and initialize all of the list item UI components
        val imageView: ImageView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.dog_image)
        val dogName: TextView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.dog_name)
        val dogAge: TextView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.dog_age)
        val dogHobbies: TextView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.dog_hobbies)
        var dogSex = "n/a"
        val showDetailsButton: Button = view!!.findViewById(R.id.details_button)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DogCardViewHolder {
        // Use a conditional to determine the layout type and set it accordingly.
        //  if the layout variable is Layout.GRID the grid list item should be used. Otherwise the
        //  the vertical/horizontal list item should be used.
        val layoutType = when(layout) {
            GRID -> R.layout.grid_list_item
            else -> R.layout.vertical_horizontal_list_item
        }

        // Inflate the layout
        val adapterLayout =LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(layoutType, parent, false)

        // Null should not be passed into the view holder. This should be updated to reflect
        //  the inflated layout.
        return DogCardViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DogCardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val resources = context?.resources

        // Get the data at the current position
        val item = data[position]

        // Set the image resource for the current dog
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(item.imageResourceId)

        // Set the text for the current dog's name
        holder.dogName.text = item.name

        // Set the text for the current dog's age
        holder.dogAge.text = resources?.getString(R.string.dog_age, item.age)

        // Set the text for the current dog's hobbies by passing the hobbies to the
        // R.string.dog_hobbies string constant.
        holder.dogHobbies.text = resources?.getString(R.string.dog_hobbies, item.hobbies)

        // Passing an argument to the string resource looks like:
        // resources?.getString(R.string.dog_hobbies, dog.hobbies)

        // Set the dog's sex variable
        holder.dogSex = item.sex

        // Declare context var
        val context = holder.itemView.context

        // Setting up OnClickListener
        holder.showDetailsButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(DOG_IMAGE, item.imageResourceId.toInt())
            intent.putExtra(DOG_NAME, holder.dogName.toString())
            intent.putExtra(DOG_AGE, holder.dogAge.toString())
            intent.putExtra(DOG_HOBBIES, holder.dogHobbies.toString())
            intent.putExtra(DOG_SEX, holder.dogSex.toString())
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should read the intent extras in onCreate().

Comment: Please do not put solutions in the question. Add a new answer below with the solution and mark it as your preferred one

Comment: Sorry, I won't do it again. I can't add an answer to my own question yet, since I have less than 15 reputation.